# Updating single table frequently vs using another table and CRON to import changes into main table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table with login logs which is EXTREMELY busy and large InnoDB table. New rows are inserted all the time, the table is queried by other parts of the system, it is by far the busiest table in the DB. In this table, there is `logid` which is `PRIMARY KEY` and its generated as a random hash by software (not auto increment ID). I also want to store some data like number of items viewed.

```
create table loginlogs
(
    logid             bigint unsigned        primary key,
    some_data         varchar(255),
    viewed_items      biging unsigned
)
```

viewed_items is a value that will get updated for multiple rows very often (assume thousands of updates / second). The dilemma I am facing now is:

Should I

```
UPDATE loginlogs SET viewed_items = XXXX WHERE logid = YYYYY
```

or should I create

```
create table loginlogs_viewed_items
(
    logid             bigint unsigned        primary key,
    viewed_items      biging unsigned,
    exported          tinyint unsigned default 0
)
```

and then execute with CRON

```
UPDATE loginlogs_viewed_items t
  INNER JOIN loginlogs l ON l.logid = t.logid
SET
  t.exported = 1,
  l.viewed_items = t.viewed_items
WHERE
  t.exported = 0;
```

e.g. every hour?

Note that either way the viewed_items counter will be updated MANY TIMES for one logid, it can be even 100 / hour / logid and there is tons of rows. So whichever table I chose for this, either the main one or the separate one, it will be getting updated quite frequently.

I want to avoid unnecessary locking of loginlogs table and at the same time I do not want to degrade performance by duplicating data in another table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I wonder why you'd want to change log entries and not just add new ones...

But anyway, as you said either way the updates have to happen, whether individually or in bulk.

If you have less busy time windows updating in bulk then might have an advantage. Otherwise the bulk update may have more significant impact when running in contrast to individual updates that might "interleave" more with the other operations making the impact less "feelable".

If the column you need to update is not needed all the time, you could think of having a separate table just for this column. That way queries that just need the other columns may be less affected by the updates.

Answer (score 0):

"Tons of rows" -- To some people, that is "millions".  To others, even "billions" is not really big.  Please provide some numbers; the answer can be different.  Meanwhile, here are some general principles.

I will assume the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

- `UPDATEing` one row at a time is 10 times as costly as updating 100 rows at a time.
- `UPDATEing` more than 1000 rows in a single statement is problematic.  It will lock each row, potentially leading to delays in other statements and maybe even deadlocks.
- Having a 'random' `PRIMARY KEY` (as opposed to `AUTO_INCREMENT` or something roughly chronologically ordered) is very costly when the table is bigger than the buffer_pool.  How much RAM do you have?
- "the table is queried by other parts of the system" -- by the random PK?  One row at a time?  How frequently?
- Please elaborate on how `exported` works.  For example, does it get reset to 0 by something else?
- Is there a single client doing all the work?  Or are there multiple servers throwing data and queries at the table?  (Different techniques are needed.)